# MVC Controller Not Receiving Parameter Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, .net-4.6.1

Regardless of how I format my URLs, I get a null parameter exception.  I've tried it every way I can think of right now.  It was working and then it just stopped.  So I reverted my last change to see if that fixed it but it didn't.  Now, even in previous (working) copies, it doesn't work.  I was also getting compiler errors so I cleaned the solution, rebuilt, restarted my machine (and VS), and still nothing.

This is NOT an issue with the route mappings.  That's all I can find when I try to search for my issue.  I did play with that quite a bit just to make sure.

I'm getting the following error message:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ViewJobs(System.Guid)' in
>   'MyProject.Controllers.RecruitingController'. An optional parameter
>   must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>   optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

My method looks like this (pretty typical):

```
public class RecruitingController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ViewJobs(Guid id)
    {
        var ListView = RecruitingLogic.GetListView(id);
        return View("ViewJobs", ListView);
    }
}
```

**Note**: I've tried changing this to a nullable guid but that didn't work.  I honestly didn't expect it to though.  I also tried moving the action to another controller.  That too did not work.

**Note 2**: I did observe this to be null.  It's not an invalid error message.  I also have action/parameter logging setup as an action filter so I was able to refer back and find the exact time when it stopped working.  You could see the action receiving non-null values and then bam, it just stopped.

The route mapping:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

In terms of urls, I'ved tried many.  However, these are the few that were working for me...until they just stopped.

https://localhost:12345/recruiting/viewjobs/B77A156-622C-E811-80D4-005056865C51
https://localhost:12345/recruiting/viewjobs?id=B77A156-622C-E811-80D4-005056865C51
https://localhost:12345/recruiting/viewjobs/?id=B77A156-622C-E811-80D4-005056865C51

I'm at a loss right now.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the route configuration has lower case `id`, can you update the action signature to use lowercase `id` parameter and try.

```
public ActionResult ViewJobs(Guid id)
```

Comment: I tried this already.  Sorry, I couldn't remember everything when making the initial post.  This didn't work unfortunately.  In addition to changing the case both in the controllers as well as in the route mapping, I also tried changing the parameter's  nullability.

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder`is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You may have confused an optional URL parameter (UrlParameter.Optional) with an optional parameter on the action method itself. The routing table is trying to find an action that allows for an optional id parameter, but Guid isn't nullable by default. Try

```
public class RecruitingController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ViewJobs(Guid? id)
    {
        var ListView = RecruitingLogic.GetListView(id);
        return View("ViewJobs", ListView);
    }
}
```

or

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
);
```

Comment: As stated in my initial post, I've already tried this.  In fact, I even played with the route mapping as you suggested.  I know it's hard to believe it isn't working.  I too am having a hard time because I've never had this issue before.  If I make the guid nullable, it passes in null still.  It might get rid of the system-generated exception, but that value should not be null to begin with.  So this does not solve the issue unfortunately.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bit where you said you'd tried the nullable value, but on second reading I wasn't sure if you'd tried removing the UrlParameter.Optional flag as well. Have you tried any of the other mechanisms for defining the default route, e.g. `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();`? I can understand your frustration - this looks like a fairly well-trodden problem (I can see some other questions that are painfully close to duplicates, but I don't wish to mark your question as such). Are you able to reproduce the problem in isolation?